# Why does the inpaint method not remove the text from IC image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-preprocessing

I am trying to mask out the marking on an IC but the `inpaint` method from OpenCV does not work correctly.

[image: inpainting dies]

The left image is the original image (after cropping the ROI). The middle image is the mask I generated through threshholding. The right image is the result of the inpainting method.

This is what I did:

```
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 3, cv2.INPAINT_NS)
```

I played around with the third parameter of the inpainting method but it does nothing good.

I saw an question here where someone used exactly the same approach and he also had a dark image where the contrasts are not so distinguished. I also tried both inpainting algorithms, Telea and NS.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly, dilate the `mask` used for the inpainting. Also, enlarging the inpaint radius will give slightly better results.

That'd be my suggestion:

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('ic.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Binary threshold image
mask = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Remove small noise
inp_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask,
                            cv2.MORPH_OPEN,
                            cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5)))

# Dilate mask
inp_mask = cv2.dilate(inp_mask,
                      cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (15, 15)))

# Inpaint
dst = cv2.inpaint(img, inp_mask, 15, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

# Show results
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Thresholded image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(inp_mask, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Inpaint mask')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(dst, cmap='gray'), plt.title('Inpainted image')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And, that'd be the output(s):

[image: Outputs]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc3
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you!
That works perfect :)
So the problem was that the mask was too small?

Comment: @NECben067 Correct!